# C++ - cURL - difference between using multiple easy_init with std::async and single multi_init

Tags: c++, curl

In my C++ program, I am downloading data from web. I can have up to 100 downloads in concurent, but they are usually not started at once and often, there can be only 4 etc.

Currently, I am using `curl_easy_init` and `std::async` to run download in the background. 
I have read about `curl_multi_init`. From what I understand, it is just an async wrapper made by cURL developers. Am I correct, or is there any other reason, why I should use it instead of multiple async jobs with easy_init?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curl_multi_` subsystem is fully asynchronous which has a number of advantages, such as:

1. It does not consume an arbitrary number of threads. Each call to `std::async` will create a thread. If this thread creation is unbounded, you will have a program that could run out of resources unexpectedly.
2. Transfers can be interrupted or cancelled under your control.
3. It will be more efficient, as all transfers share the same IO loop. The only point of contention is the `select()` call (or equivalent for `select_multi_socket`).

Comment: Another added bonus with using the multi interface is then the connection cache is shared by default instead of having one separate in each thread. Although libcurl offers an API to share it across too with a little more work...

Comment: @hanshenrik I have assumed the launch::async case. But sure , the standard say 'as if a new thread'. The problem of unbounded thread creation remains though. Nothing in the standard prevents it, so we must assume that it may happen (as indeed it does on gcc and clang)